# Why are my fields value automatically set on [Object HTMLInputElement] in my Ionic 4 form?

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework

Like the title say, any idea why are my fields value automatically set on [Object HTMLInputElement] in my Ionic 4 form ?

I got other forms that poses no problems using the form driven validation but this one directly input [Object HTMLInputElement] in my fields as soon as the component load.

I tried setting the value to "" with no success.

```
<ion-header>
<ion-title>Connexion</ion-title>
</ion-header>
<ion-card>
   <form #connexionForm (ngSubmit)="connexion(connexionForm)">
     <ion-item>
       <ion-input required type="mail" placeholder="Adresse mail" 
         name="mail" [(ngModel)]="connexionForm.mail" #mail="ngModel"></ion- 
          input>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-input required type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" 
       name="password" [(ngModel)]="connexionForm.password"
       #password="ngModel"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-button ion-button round text-center type="submit" 
     *ngIf="!password.errors?.required && 
     !mail.errors?.required">Connexion</ion-button>
 </form>
</ion-card>
```

thanks.

EDIT: it appears that even when i type values in my fields and submit the form, the inputted values stay [Object HTMLInputElement]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using as `ngModel` the actual form reference + property. If you have a variable named `connexionForm`, you need to either change the name of that variable or change the template reference. Here we change the form template reference. Also add `ngForm`:

```html
<form #myConnexionForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="connexion(myConnexionForm.value)">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input 
         required 
         type="email" <!-- Should be "email", not "mail"-->
         placeholder="Adresse mail" 
         name="mail" 
         [(ngModel)]="connexionForm.mail" 
         #mail="ngModel">
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input 
       required 
       type="password" 
       placeholder="Mot de passe" 
       name="password" 
       [(ngModel)]="connexionForm.password" 
       #password="ngModel">
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button ion-button round text-center type="submit" *ngIf="password.touched 
    && !password.errors?.required && !mail.errors?.required">
    Connexion
  </ion-button>
</form>
```

TS:

```ts
connexionForm = {}; // your variable

connexion(formvalues: any) {
  console.log(formvalues.mail, formvalues.password);
  // you also have your values in "connexionForm"
  console.log(this.connexionForm);
}
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear! :)